# Bash Script using sdiff to compare content from two remote urls

Tags: bash, curl, sdiff

I am trying to use a simple bash command to cause the sdiff of two curl requests

```
$ sdiff -l -w 140 $(curl -s "https:/URL/1/2/thing.php?d=20190202") \
                  $(curl -s "https:/URL/1/2/thing.php?d=20190203")
```

If I download the two curl requests into files, then sdiff the files it works. is it possible to consolidate into one command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html):

```
sdiff ... <(curl ...) <(curl ...)
```

Comment: nailed it! exactly what was needed!